# Error to send data to tablet through bluetooth device

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth

I'm facing the following problem:
I am connecting two devices via Bluetooth socket, one tablet android and a bluetooth device like reader barcode, up to now it's ok, the problem is, when a read the barcode by the bluetooth device and I send it to tablet, the bar code sometimes it's sent in two parts, for example, if I read a barcode with content "212154521212", the tablet receive  "2121" and after "54521212", Anyone know tell me what should I do to avoid this?

Thanks in advanced.

My code that read the data from bluetooth device:

[code]
    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {

```
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private BluetoothSocket socket;

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;

        InputStream tmpIn = null;

        try {

            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            new LogDeErrosRodesTablet(e);
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            Log.e(TAG, "Erro no construtor da classe ConnectedThread.");

        }

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
    }

    public void run() {     
        // continua lendo o inputstream até ocorrer um erro

        while (true) {

            int read = 0;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[128];

            do {

                try {

                    read = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                    Log.e(TAG, "read: " + read);
                    final String data = new String(buffer, 0, read);
                    Log.e(TAG, "data: " + data);

                    //TODO
                    //send data only (bar code) only after read all
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString(TelaInserirPedido.CODIGO_BARRAS, data);
                    Message message = new Message();
                    message.what = TelaInserirPedido.MSG_COD_BARRAS;
                    message.setData(bundle);

                    //Send a message with data
                    handler.sendMessage(message);

                } catch(Exception ex) {
                    read = -1;
                    return;
                }

                Log.e(TAG, "inside while.");

            } while (read > 0);

            Log.e(TAG, "outside of while.");
        }

    }

    public void cancel () {
        try {
            socket.close ();
        } catch ( IOException e) { }
    }

}
```

[/code]

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a Bluetooth error. The Bluetooth device is sending all of the data to your application, but you are reading the stream before all of the data have been received. You could check for the amount of bytes available() on the stream before reading, if you know the exact length of the data; you could concatenate the results of all of the reads until you reach a known end point. Or you could put in an arbitrary time delay and hope the transmission completed in that time.

You would create the Bundle and Message after the while loop that collects the input string, because you don't know the entire string until that loop finishes. (Unless you are expecting multiple strings in one connection, in which case you need more complex code to handle partial numbers).

Answer (score 0):

Use OutputStream.flush() to force send the all data.

Comment: In any moment I have used an OutPutStream.

Comment: I Have done this: socket.getOutputStream().flush(); But no success

Comment: No, you have to add OutputStream.flush() after OutputStream.write(bytes)
Like this: try { OutputStream.write(bytes);
                 OutputStream.flush(); }

Comment: In any moment I use an OutputStream object, I simply read the data that Bluetooth device send to me, after that, I'm trying to send it through of Handler, Bundle and Message. Definetly I have not used a OutputStream.

Comment: any idea? I still continue with the problem.